# Replace number in a template file with numbers from a list and output to different files

Tags: awk, sed

`file1.txt` is like:

```
$view->name = '12483291';
...
$view->human_name = '12483291';
```

Also I have some numbers in `file2`:

```
8789
53416
673425
```

What I need to do is: for each number in the above column, replace the '12483291' value, and create a new file named after the replacement number.

Desired output:

`file: 8789.inc`

```
$view->name = '8789'
...
$view->human_name = '8789'
```

`file: 53416.inc`

```
$view->name = '53416'
...
$view->human_name = '53416'
```

`file: 673425.inc`

```
$view->name = '673425'
...
$view->human_name = '673425'
```

How would you approach this?

A few of my attempts, but without getting the result I want:

`sed "s/12483291/$(cat file2)/" file1 > 8789.inc`

The above works if `file2` has only one line, and I have to run the command as many times as the values in `file2`, manually giving the name of the result file.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works. Questions of the form "I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code" are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask], and especially read [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: should i post here what i have tried and did not work? all my attempts or just one?

Comment: There are about 1000 ways to do this. The easiest is probably a simple bash loop with a sed on top. No need to fire up python. You could also do this in awk, but it is a bit overkill.

Comment: Just update your question by clicking [edit] (below your question, next to your name) and post one or two methods that did not work for you and why they did not work.

Comment: Try the following: `while read -r n; do sed "s/'12483291'/'${n}'/g" file.inc > "${n}.inc"; done < list.txt`

Comment: the files are named like 12044236^M.inc and $view->name = '12483291'; has become ';iew->name = '12044236 why is this happening? i have used your above suggested command. The list.txt is created on windows, i wonder if this the problem

Comment: does `cat -v file1` show up `^M` at the end of the line? If so, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45772525/why-does-my-tool-output-overwrite-itself-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: you are totally correct, so many things to learn...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n 's/.*/sed "s#12483291#&#g" file1 >&.inc/e' file2
```

Replace the number `1248329` in the template file1 by each number in file2 and name the file produced by that number with `.inc` appended.

Answer (score 1):

If your file has dos-style line ending, see [Why does my tool output overwrite itself and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45772525/why-does-my-tool-output-overwrite-itself-and-how-do-i-fix-it) first.

---

With `GNU awk`

```
awk -v q="'" -v s="'12483291'" 'NR==FNR{a[$1]; next}
    {for(k in a) {print gensub(s, q k q, 1) > k".inc"}}' f2 f1
```

- `-v q="'"` just a handy variable with single quote character
- `-v s="'12483291'"` the field value to be replaced
- `NR==FNR{a[$1]; next}` here `NR` has overall record number and `FNR` has current file record number. So, `NR==FNR` will be `true` only for first file. The array `a` will store the first field as keys.
- `for(k in a)` for the second file, loop over all the keys in array `a`

  - `gensub(s, q k q, 1)` change the field value with value of the key (note that this will replace only first match and assumes `s` doesn't have any regex metacharacter)
  - output of `gensub` is then redirected to a filename based on the key
- Add `-v RS='\r\n'` to handle dos-style input

---

With other `awk` you may run into too many files issue if `f2` has large number of lines. Change the loop content to `{line=$0; sub(s, q k q, line); f=k".inc"; print line >> f; close(f)}`. This assumes `.inc` files don't already exist, otherwise, you'll get content appended.